# iPhone Dev - Drawing Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, drawing

first time user and iPhone Developer Novice. My question focuses on the architecture of my application rather than nitty gritty code. My question to you is: Am I on the right track or do I need to rethink my approach to this part of the application?

I am trying to make a simple "connect the dots" application. My application has working free-hand draw-by-touch functionality and I am using UIButtons to represent each dot.

I've approached this problem by calling for the center property of 2 UIButtons(the dots) and placing conditions to only draw a line if the start/end CGPoints are the center coordinates for these 2 dots. This isn't working!

So my question is:

Is UIButtons the best approach for representing each dot? If so, what functionality should be added to each dot? It seems like a strong candidate since you could call the center property and get it's center coordinate. But since I've run into problems with this, I've considered a single pixel probably isn't big enough to place conditions on.

If UIButtons aren't the best approach for representing each dot, what is a better alternative?

Lastly, I've spent a great amount of time researching the properties and functionality of UIButtons because of this problem. I can't find a good reference to the descriptions of the Sent Events options available through the UIButton. Does anyone know a good blog/reference?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

UIButton tapping is not advisable. Here is a sample for you to free-hand drawing by touch.

http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024

Comment: Thank you for the link, coincidentally that is the sample I referred to for my application. Would anyone know of a blog/reference to UIButton Sent Events descriptions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of focusing on `UIButtons` and their events, I removed the `UIButtons` and focused on the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnd` methods. I incorporated `CGContext` methods to only draw lines when a `UITouch` is registered at a specific initial location and a specific current location. While I am not sure if this is the most ideal/efficient answer to my problem, it works well and has allowed me to move on to the next phase of my project. If anyone has suggestions to improve this solution, it would be greatly appreciated. Below is a snippet of the code I used for this solution:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        image1_.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    initialPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    //If initial touch to screen is within 15 pixels of Dot 1, set coordinates to Dot 1
    if(initialPoint.x > 36 && initialPoint.x < 66 && initialPoint.y > 161 && initialPoint.y < 191)
    {
        initialPoint.x = 51.0;
        initialPoint.y = 176.0;
    }

    //If initial touch to screen is within 15 pixels of Dot 2, set coordinates to Dot 2    
    if(initialPoint.x > 199.5 && initialPoint.x < 229.5 && initialPoint.y > 170.5 && initialPoint.y < 190.5)
    {
        initialPoint.x = 214.5;
        initialPoint.y = 175.5;
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    //If current touch to screen is within 15 pixels of Dot 2, and the initial touch is
    //set to Dot 1, draw line
    if(currentPoint.x > 199.5 && currentPoint.x < 229.5 && currentPoint.y > 170.5 && currentPoint.y < 190.5 && initialPoint.x == 51.0 && initialPoint.y == 176.0)
    {
        currentPoint.x = 214.5;
        currentPoint.y = 175.5;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [image1_.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                             self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapSquare);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 4.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), initialPoint.x, initialPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        image1_.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        lineIsDrawn = YES;
    }    

    //If current touch to screen is within 15 pixels of Dot 3, and the initial touch is
    //set to Dot 2, and a line has already been drawn between Dot 1 & Dot 2, draw line    
    if(currentPoint.x > 155.5 && currentPoint.x < 180.5 && currentPoint.y > 0 && currentPoint.y < 28.5 && initialPoint.x == 214.5 && initialPoint.y == 175.5 && lineIsDrawn == YES)
    {
        currentPoint.x = 170.5;
        currentPoint.y = 13.5;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [image1_.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                             self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapSquare);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 4.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);        
        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), initialPoint.x, initialPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        image1_.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
```